# How do I create a subclass of Str?

Tags: raku

I have this class which is basically a wrapper for a Str attribute:

```
use Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses;
unit class Vimwiki::File::ContentStr;

has Str $!content;

submethod BUILD( :$content ) {
    $!content = $content;
}

method gist {
    return $!content;
}

method capitalize-headers() {
    $!content = Vimwiki::File::TextProcessingClasses::HeadlineCapitalizer.new.capitalize-headers($!content);
}
```

Seems like it would be more efficient to subclass the core `Str` class with something like this, similar to a trick I learned for subclassing `IO::Path`:

```
class Blah is Str {
    method !SET-SELF() {
        self;
    }

    method new(Str:D $string) {
        self.Str::new($string)!SET-SELF();
    }    
}

my $blah = Blah.new('hello');
say $blah;
```

However, this throws an error: `Default constructor for 'Blah' only takes named arguments`

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're looking at sub-Classing instead of adding a `Role` (but maybe I don't understand the problem you're addressing?): https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#Roles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since constructors in Raku are ordinary methods then - at least if written correctly - they work virtually, so there's no need to declare your own. Subclassing `Str` is at a minimum:

```
class SubStr is Str {
}
```

We can verify it does the right thing as follows:

```
given SubStr.new(value => "hi") {
    say .WHAT;  # (SubStr) - correct type
   .say;        # hi - correct value
}
```

This does not appear to be particularly well documented.

Note also that `Str` is a box around the "native" `str`, so if the efficiency concern is about memory consumption, then your own boxing around a `str` will consume no more than `Str` itself.

```
unit class Vimwiki::File::ContentStr;
has str $!content;
...
```

Comment: Aweome, thanks. I was thinking more along the lines of coding efficiency. If, for example, I want to do $StrSubclass.uc(), I don't want to have to write a wrapper method for it. I'm having a problem, though, with my idea: my subclassed Str objects are immutable. Wonder if I can get the best of both worlds.

Comment: Maybe there is something like autoload where I can call the method on the attribute if it doesn't exist?

Comment:  "If, for example, I want to do `$StrSubclass.uc()`, I don't want to have to write a wrapper method for it." You don't. For example `class Str2 is Str {}; my $foo := Str2.new(value => 'string'); say $foo.uc; # STRING`.  "my subclassed `Str` objects are immutable". `Str` objects are immutable, so straight-forward subclasses of them are as well. Thus `"foo".=uc; ` and `$foo.=uc` both yield `Cannot modify an immutable ... (string)`.

Answer (score 0):

Holy crap, I took a wild guess and passed the `$string` in with a `value` argument:

```
class Blah is Str {
    method new(Str:D $string) {
        self.Str::new(value => $string);
    }    

    method whoa() {
        say self;
    }
}


my $blah = Blah.new('hello');
say $blah.flip;
$blah.whoa # it works!;
```

Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Well, attributes are documented in the class itself. Raku is "strangely consistent": The rest is just logical. If you think, however, it deserves a specific sidebar, just raise an issue.

Answer (score -1):

See the recently merged PR #4105 at https://github.com/raku/doc. It shows a practical example where we create a new class to extend the core class. I cannot say for certain, but I believe the augmented class
does NOT change internal state of the base class, so it should be
safe for threaded use.

There is a closed Rakudo core PR #5031 which discusses the addition of similar methods to **IO::Path**. The following example, with a slightly different name and augmented methods with different names, is in a recently published module called **IO::Stem**. It was published as a module because we could not get a consensus on what to call all parts of **IO::Path.basename**.

```
unit class IO::Barename is IO::Path; # IO::Path is the core class
                                     # which is not easily modified
method new(|c) {
    # In this case we must always return the parent object for the
    # subclass
    return self.IO::Path::new(|c);
}

# The subclass will have the augmented method coded in terms
# of the base class
use MONKEY-TYPING;
augment class IO::Path {
    method barename {
        self.extension("").basename;
    }
}
```